# configure "Idea" to display src/main/java as one folder

Tags: intellij-idea

Just started to move to Intellij Idea and stuck with some UI settings:
Is possible to configure "Idea" to display src/main/java as one folder like in eclipse?
It's really annoying click 3 times just get to your sources.

Comment: I'm 7 years late to the party but here I am. There is an open issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-201512 so I don't think it's possible at the moment

Answer (score 6):

You can configure 'Project Structure -> Modules' and in your module set folder 'java' under 'src/main/' to be indentidied by IDE as Source Folder. Than Idea will collapse 'src/main' as one item in project navigator.

Comment: This looks like the right answer and the way Eclipse works.  But I couldn't figure out how to set the java folder under src/main to be the Source Folder (In Eclipse, you navigate to the folder and set it as a source folder from the context popup).  No such option in the context sensitive popup in Intellij and I couldn't figure out where to set that in Project Structure-> Modules.

Comment: In IntelliJ Community Edition 2016.1, you can go to the Sources tab in the File->Project Structure menu option. The "source" folders are color coded blue (on my machine), tests are green, excluded files are red, etc. You can right-click a folder and de-select the "source" icon from the root /src directory, and do the opposite on the folder you want to now be a "source" directory.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this just sets the colour of the directory (and what the compiler is looking for?) but doesn't actually collapse the src/main/java folder... Still not sure how to do that.

Comment: It does collapse it only if there are no other folders in src/ and in src/main/. If there's also src/test/... and src/main/resources/ it still doesn't flatten the structure in any of the views.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's happening in Eclipse, but if you got no other folders under `src` or `main`, you can use the `Compact Empty Middle Packages` option.

[image]

Comment: in eclipse you don't need to click on src -> main -> java to see your packages. It shows scr/main/java as one source folder. Thanks for answer anyway.

Comment: You can also switch the Project panel to the Packages view to show just sources.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I have found so far is to create a new scope.

File -> Settings -> Scopes

Call it something like "Eclipse View" and set the Pattern to

!file:*.iml&&!file:.idea//*&&!file:.settings//*&&!file:.classpath&&!file:.project

Then select the new "Eclipse View" scope in the Project tool window.  It is not a perfect match, but it is pretty close.

Comment: This shows packages as folders, e.g. `com/foo/bar` instead of `com.foo.bar`.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't flatten src/main/java (or any other of 4 folders in src/) in Eclipse View. It just hid some files.